# Overleaf do not write ≠

Tags: symbols, overleaf

I'm just wondering why Overleaf does not write ≠ (`\ne`). Instead, it write =.

Is there any solution of this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you try `\neq` instead  of `\ne`?

Comment: Thank you. Always the same problem, even with \neq.

Comment: Then as always on this site please provide a full but minimal example displaying this problem

Comment: did you get an error message that `\not` was not in math mode?

Comment: What font package are you using?

Comment: Nothing, instead writing ≠, it write =

Answer (score 5):

This works perfectly on Overleaf: https://v2.overleaf.com/read/nmghqystczhy.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\ne$ 
\end{document}
```

This is what appears:

[image]

I think it's only a zooming problem, even with your template (https://v2.overleaf.com/read/zjpfypcqzxgn) the symbol is correct:

[image]

but if you zoom out it appears as if it has only one horizontal dash:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but always =.

Comment: I think something is wrong with my latex there.

Comment: @DiegoHavez can you make a small project on overleaf and share it as CarLaTex  has done here? then we can see your example

Comment: David lol. CarlaTex, when I use \ne, I see =.

Comment: Yes I will now.

Comment: Look for "Bredele" in Overleaf. It is an example of a thesis.

Comment: Even if you use packages there (Bredele), it will always give you =

Comment: https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/bredele/wyhhrmqjbdbv

Comment: It is in french, sorry.

Comment: Which symbol? =?

Comment: I can't see.The page said : Restricted, sorry you don't have permission to load this page.

Comment: I just saw the symbol. I think I will change this pdflatex. Thank you very much for your help.