# Math Symbols \neq with Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, relation-symbols

Can someone maybe help me out and let me know how to set:

```
≠
```

in LaTeX? I am using Overleaf. I have tried `\≠`  but it did not work out.

Thanks in advance. Greetings.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477476/overleaf-do-not-write-%E2%89%A0/477479#477479

Comment: `\ne` or `\neq`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477476/4427

Comment: Hm, the question is answered. How can I close this thread now? Or do I even have to?

Comment: @FelixDe It is already closed.